# Journal of Latex class files

Tags: journal, ieee

what is journal of latex class files? is it a journal or something else? I have found that it is a document preparation format but i am looking for a journal. Even i have found few papers those claiming that they are published in journal of latex in class files (Link of research article: http://publilgep.geeps.centralesupelec.fr/papers/001416.pdf ) can anybody help me.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184131/how-to-remove-journal-of-latex-class-above-the-title-in-ieeetrans) on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it programming related question?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5):

This "journal" is just what it says on every page when you use the standard IEEE LaTeX template for writing a paper. Authors should change that - some don't notice. Like Mark said in the comments, see [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184131/how-to-remove-journal-of-latex-class-above-the-title-in-ieeetrans) for how to change it if you're an author.